# elsif directive in c++ with 3 options

Tags: c++, directive

I would like to be able to switch my feed between an image, a video and a webcam.
Atm i try this:

```
#define F_WEBCAM
#define F_VIDEO
#define F_IMAGE

#define FEED(F_WEBCAM)
```

Somewhere else:

```
#if defined(FEED) && FEED == F_WEBCAM
    ofVideoGrabber vidGrabber;
#elif defined(FEED) && FEED == F_VIDEO
    ofVideoPlayer vidPlayer;
#elif defined(FEED) && FEED == F_IMAGE
    // code for image
#endif
```

But i get the following error:

> Expected value in expression

Is this possible the way i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare, you need to define your macro constants with values. This will solve your issue:

```
#define F_WEBCAM 1
#define F_VIDEO 2
#define F_IMAGE 3

#define FEED F_WEBCAM
```